# Group theory and Hydrogen-like wave functions

Tags: group-theory, quantum-mechanics

I'm reading Pauling and Wilson's QM, in one place it is written that the $n^2$ wave functions $\psi_{n,l,m}(r,\theta,\phi)$ (for an H-like atom) with the same value of $n$ form a completed group. How? What is the law of composition for which they even form a group? I couldn't get any references online or offline. Any suggestions/references are welcome.

Comment: It is not group in the sense of group theory, but group as in "group of things" in English language.  It is a complete orthonormal basis (for the space of solutions of certain energy, or subspace with $(n,l)$) for us mathematicians.  Note though the book was from 1930s, before physicists took up the group-theoretic language.

Answer (score 2):

They are a complete set, or grouping (not group), of functions solving the Schroedinger equation for such an atom with energy characterized by that posited *n*. That is, they are a complete basis of all solutions for that energy.

When it comes to symmetry groups commuting with the hamiltonian, there is first SO(3), with quadratic Casimir ${\mathbf L}\cdot {\mathbf L}$ eigenvalues $\ell (\ell+1)$, $\ell= 0,1,2,...,n-1$, that is, *n* different irreducible representations of SO(3), each with dimension $2\ell+1$. One of the three generators of SO(3), namely $L_z$ has eigenvalues *m*, $|m|\leq \ell$, and  connects states in a representation labelled by $\ell$; but cannot connect states for different $\ell$s—to do that you need generators of the [larger symmetry of these atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector#Quantum_mechanics_of_the_hydrogen_atom), SO(4)~ SO(3)×SO(3).

You might easily show the totality of states then is $\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1} (2\ell +1)=n^2$. They comprise a complete expansion basis for all solutions with that energy.